# C integration runs too slow

Tags: c, runtime, integration

I'm trying to write c code for Romberg integration from -inf to inf.
where "HERE" wrote is where I give the number and run the function.
When the number more than 20 is or sometimes also with 15, code doesnt run or takes too long.

I'm pretty sure it's becaus of function but I dont really have idea which part should be changed.

Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#define eps pow(10,-8)
double f (double a, double x, double z){
    return exp(-pow(x,2)/pow(a,2))/sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(z,2));
}
                       
long double romberg(double f(double, double, double), double a, double xa, double xe, double z,int N){

    double *Rpre=malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    double *Rcur=malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    //double R1[n],R2[n];
    //double Rpre=&R1[0],*Rcur=&R2[0]; //Rpre fuer previous row, Rcur fuer current row
    double h =xe-xa;
    Rpre[0]=0.5*h*(f(a,xa,z)+f(a,xe,z)); //erste Trapaze
    
    for(int i=1;i<N;i++){
        h*=0.5;
        double sum=0;
        
        for(int j=1;j<=pow(2,i-1);j++){//bis 2^(n-1)
            sum+=f(a,xa+(2*j-1)*h,z);
        }
        Rcur[0]=h*sum+0.5*Rpre[0];//R[i][0]
        
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            double n_k=pow(4,j);
            Rcur[j]=(n_k*Rcur[j-1]-Rpre[j-1]) /(n_k-1); //R[i][j]
        }
        
       /* if(i>1&&fabs(Rpre[i-1]-Rcur[i])<eps){ //Wenn die rel. Genauigkeit erfuellt ist.
            return Rcur[i];
        }*/
       double *temp=Rpre; //wenn es bis zum Ende der Reihe laeuft, muss Current Wert Previous Wert sein
        Rpre=Rcur;
        Rcur=temp;
        
    }printf("%25.16e\n",Rpre[N-1]);
    return Rpre[N-1];
            

        
}
            
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double a[4]={0.02,1,2,4};
    double N=LONG_MAX; //maximale double wert
    double alpha=1/sqrt(M_PI);
    
    //long double ** R= malloc( N * sizeof(long double ) );
//printf("%lf",N);
    
 /* Parameter für den z-Bereich 
   */
  double const zmin = 0.;
  double const zmax = 5.;
  int const znum = 100;

  /* Schleife über z-Werte, für die integriert werden soll
   */
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
    char filename[32];
    sprintf(filename, "h21_a_%.2lf.txt",a[i]);
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    
 for ( int iz = 0; iz <= znum; iz++ )
  {

    double z = zmin + ( zmax - zmin ) / (double)znum * iz ;
     double r=romberg(f,a[i],-N,N,z,20); //HERE
    fprintf(fp,"%lf\t%25.16e\n",z,r*alpha/a[i]);
     

  }fclose(fp);
}
   // free(R);
    return 0;
}
```

I changed the variable to *var instead of var
and use only two 1-d arrays instead of R[n][n] 2-d array.

++
changed Rpre and Rcur into R,
inf as 2^27,
and the for- loop with `int x = 1 << (i - 1); for (int j = 1; j <= x; j++) {`
pow(x,2) to x*x

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253700/discussion-on-question-by-suess-c-integration-runs-too-slow); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm pretty sure it's becaus of function but I dont really have idea which part should be changed.

No, **it's characteristic of the algorithm** you are using.  Your computation scales extremely quickly (O(2<sup>*n*</sup>)) with respect to the value of the last parameter to `romberg()`, which is the one you are asking about.  For any given function, it is not surprising that *n* doesn't have to be very large before the program runs longer than you are willing to wait.

You may be able to increase that limit very slightly by code and compilation improvements, but even making it twice as fast gets you only an increase of 1 in the *n* that you can compute in any fixed amount of time.

You should also take some computational considerations into account, especially around floating-point representation.  FP representation is not exact, and you've chosen integration bounds that will almost certainly be both

- very far into the range where the mathematical result of your function cannot be distinguished from zero in your system's floating-point representation, and
- very far into the range where intermediate results in the computation of your function suffer from substantial loss of precision.

At the same time, using such large bounds means that you need to go to pretty large `n` to get a good estimate of the integral, because it is such a small proportion of the overall range that contributes meaningfully to that estimate.

Possible algorithmic improvements include:

- Instead of using a fixed *n*, use an adaptive approach wherein you stop refining the estimate when its relative change drops below some threshold (perhaps limited to a maximum *n*).
- Narrow the integration bounds to achieve quicker convergence (that is, at smaller *n*).  You could consider an exponential search for points where the function value stops strictly decreasing (anything past these points is just noise).  Or for functions of the particular form you are using, you could consider using +/- 2<sup>27</sup>, as this takes you just over the edge of the point where you start losing precision if your `double` has 53 bits of mantissa (as most implementations' do).  Among other options.

Answer (score 0):

A few tweaks (that produce a 1.7x speedup) ...

1. doing `(x * x)` is faster than `pow(x,2)`
2. doing `pow(2,j)` for integers is slow -- it can be replace with a shift.
3. It should only be done *once* (and *not* on each loop iteration).
4. Doing `n_k = pow(4,j)` on each loop iteration is slow
5. It can be replaced with `n_k *= 4.0`

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes. I've also added benchmark timing to the `printf` call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifndef ORIG
#define ORIG    0
#endif
#define FIX     (! ORIG)

#if 0
#define eps pow(10,-8)
#endif
double eps;

#define xsqr(_x) \
    ((_x) * (_x))

double tsczero;

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    sec -= tsczero;

    return sec;
}

double
f(double a, double x, double z)
{
// NOTE/BUG: doing (x * x) is faster than pow(x,2)
#if ORIG
    return exp(-pow(x, 2) / pow(a, 2)) / sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(z, 2));
#else
    double x2 = xsqr(x);
    return exp(-x2 / xsqr(a)) / sqrt(x2 + xsqr(z));
#endif
}

long double
romberg(double f(double, double, double), double a, double xa, double xe,
    double z, int N)
{

    double *Rpre = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    double *Rcur = malloc(N * sizeof(double));

    // double R1[n],R2[n];
    // Rpre fuer previous row, Rcur fuer current row
    // double Rpre=&R1[0],*Rcur=&R2[0];
    double h = xe - xa;

    // erste Trapaze
    Rpre[0] = 0.5 * h * (f(a, xa, z) + f(a, xe, z));

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        h *= 0.5;
        double sum = 0;

        // bis 2^(n-1)
// NOTE/BUG: doing pow(i,j) for integers is slow
// NOTE/BUG: calling this on each loop iteration is slow
#if ORIG
        for (int j = 1; j <= pow(2, i - 1); j++) {
            sum += f(a, xa + (2 * j - 1) * h, z);
        }
#else
// NOTE/FIX: replace pow with a shift and do only once
        for (int j = 1, j2 = 1 << (i - 1); j <= j2; j++) {
            sum += f(a, xa + (2 * j - 1) * h, z);
        }
#endif

        // R[i][0]
        Rcur[0] = h * sum + 0.5 * Rpre[0];

// NOTE/BUG: calling pow on each iteration is slow
#if ORIG
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            double n_k = pow(4, j);

            // R[i][j]
            Rcur[j] = (n_k * Rcur[j - 1] - Rpre[j - 1]) / (n_k - 1);
        }
#else
// NOTE/FIX: replace pow with incremental multiply
        double n_k = 1.0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            n_k *= 4.0;

            // R[i][j]
            Rcur[j] = (n_k * Rcur[j - 1] - Rpre[j - 1]) / (n_k - 1);
        }
#endif

#if EPS
        // Wenn die rel. Genauigkeit erfuellt ist.
        if (i > 1 && fabs(Rpre[i - 1] - Rcur[i]) < eps) {
            return Rcur[i];
        }
#endif
        // wenn es bis zum Ende der Reihe laeuft, muss Current Wert Previous
        // Wert sein
        double *temp = Rpre;

        Rpre = Rcur;
        Rcur = temp;
    }

// NOTE/BUG: don't include printf if doing performance measurements
#if 0
    printf("%25.16e\n", Rpre[N - 1]);
#endif

    return Rpre[N - 1];
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double a[4] = { 0.02, 1, 2, 4 };
    // maximale double wert
    double N = LONG_MAX;
    double alpha = 1 / sqrt(M_PI);

    tsczero = tscgetf();

#if 0
    long double **R = malloc(N * sizeof(long double));

    printf("%lf", N);
#endif

    eps = pow(10,-8);

    // Parameter für den z-Bereich
    double const zmin = 0.;
    double const zmax = 5.;
#if DEMO
    int const znum = DEMO;
#else
    int const znum = 100;
#endif

    // Schleife über z-Werte, für die integriert werden soll
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        char filename[32];

        sprintf(filename, "h21_a_%.2lf.txt", a[i]);
        FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");

        for (int iz = 0; iz <= znum; iz++) {
            double tscbeg = tscgetf();

            double z = zmin + (zmax - zmin) / (double) znum * iz;

            // HERE
            double r = romberg(f, a[i], -N, N, z, 20);

#if 1
            double tscend = tscgetf();
            printf("%.9f %25.16e\n", tscend - tscbeg, r);
            tscbeg = tscend;
#endif

#if 1
            fprintf(fp, "%lf\t%25.16e\n", z, r * alpha / a[i]);
#endif
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }

#if 0
    free(R);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Also ...

```
#if ORIG
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if FIX
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k -DORIG=0`

---

Elapsed times for original and fixed versions for loop iterations:

```
     Total time  Time per call
ORIG 4.069441405 0.092487305
FIX  2.395335764 0.054439449
```

Speedup is 1.699x

Here is the output for the original program *and* the fixed program (compiled with `-DDEMO=10`).

```
ORIG                                    FIX
0.098137318                      -nan   0.057743992                      -nan
0.097679134    4.2865100183969344e+13   0.055832875    4.2865100183969344e+13
0.097967627    2.1432550091984672e+13   0.055699762    2.1432550091984672e+13
0.096517395    1.4288366727989789e+13   0.055477580    1.4288366727989789e+13
0.094043442    1.0716275045992336e+13   0.056299677    1.0716275045992336e+13
0.093548951    8.5730200367938691e+12   0.058548293    8.5730200367938691e+12
0.095909685    7.1441833639948945e+12   0.055331890    7.1441833639948945e+12
0.094319706    6.1235857405670557e+12   0.055480244    6.1235857405670557e+12
0.094109384    5.3581375229961680e+12   0.055346522    5.3581375229961680e+12
0.093769347    4.7627889093299268e+12   0.056081215    4.7627889093299268e+12
0.093589583    4.2865100183969346e+12   0.055978985    4.2865100183969346e+12
0.091371239                      -nan   0.053419079                      -nan
0.092579969    4.2865100183969344e+13   0.053669294    4.2865100183969344e+13
0.091236377    2.1432550091984672e+13   0.054249677    2.1432550091984672e+13
0.090961806    1.4288366727989789e+13   0.054563181    1.4288366727989789e+13
0.090794377    1.0716275045992336e+13   0.053247944    1.0716275045992336e+13
0.090866636    8.5730200367938691e+12   0.053357693    8.5730200367938691e+12
0.092706834    7.1441833639948945e+12   0.053283874    7.1441833639948945e+12
0.090963371    6.1235857405670557e+12   0.053576597    6.1235857405670557e+12
0.091215859    5.3581375229961680e+12   0.053465706    5.3581375229961680e+12
0.091968977    4.7627889093299268e+12   0.054223244    4.7627889093299268e+12
0.091215764    4.2865100183969346e+12   0.054221564    4.2865100183969346e+12
0.091439863                      -nan   0.053886837                      -nan
0.091878234    4.2865100183969344e+13   0.056147531    4.2865100183969344e+13
0.091113353    2.1432550091984672e+13   0.053652313    2.1432550091984672e+13
0.091204614    1.4288366727989789e+13   0.053591324    1.4288366727989789e+13
0.091964998    1.0716275045992336e+13   0.053493202    1.0716275045992336e+13
0.091647607    8.5730200367938691e+12   0.053533189    8.5730200367938691e+12
0.092162252    7.1441833639948945e+12   0.053956118    7.1441833639948945e+12
0.090839403    6.1235857405670557e+12   0.054470336    6.1235857405670557e+12
0.090834735    5.3581375229961680e+12   0.053291850    5.3581375229961680e+12
0.092375710    4.7627889093299268e+12   0.053635458    4.7627889093299268e+12
0.091070728    4.2865100183969346e+12   0.056126570    4.2865100183969346e+12
0.092109321                      -nan   0.053610519                      -nan
0.091759439    4.2865100183969344e+13   0.053366779    4.2865100183969344e+13
0.092044124    2.1432550091984672e+13   0.053542467    2.1432550091984672e+13
0.090677761    1.4288366727989789e+13   0.053449231    1.4288366727989789e+13
0.091415760    1.0716275045992336e+13   0.053615699    1.0716275045992336e+13
0.090851821    8.5730200367938691e+12   0.053385493    8.5730200367938691e+12
0.093354997    7.1441833639948945e+12   0.053705318    7.1441833639948945e+12
0.091455909    6.1235857405670557e+12   0.053308070    6.1235857405670557e+12
0.091560392    5.3581375229961680e+12   0.055094212    5.3581375229961680e+12
0.091412582    4.7627889093299268e+12   0.054127111    4.7627889093299268e+12
0.090795021    4.2865100183969346e+12   0.053247249    4.2865100183969346e+12
```